# Random selection of a number from a list of numbers that is biased toward the lowest number

Tags: c++

At every moment t, I have a different set of positive integers. I need to randomly select one of them, satisfying the criteria that the probability of a particular number to be selected from the set must be **proportionally** higher, the lower is the value of the number. At moment t+1, we have another set of positive integers, and again we need to select one of them satisfying the same criteria. So on, so forth. How to do this in c++?

Comment: How much higher? What is the cumulative density function or quantile function here?

Comment: One option is to apply the [softmax function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function) to the sequence of numbers mulitplied by -1, then take a random number between 0 and 1 and pick the first element for which the cumulative sum is greater than the random number.

Comment: To be able to answer the question, you need to clarify what the distribution function is.  Is it exp(-v) or 1/(v+1), or ?? where v can be the value of an item or the position. I assume the list is ascending ?

Comment: Could you add an example? If the integers are `1`, `2` and `3`, which probability should each one have?

Comment: 1 should have double probability to be selected than 2 and triple than 3. Number 2 should have 1.5 times the probability of 3 to be selected.

Comment: And the three probability values should add 1

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to assign ranges to each number, randomize a value, and pick the number which has the range in which the randomized value is included.

Example

Input:

```
1 2 3
```

Ranges:

```
[0,300) [300, 450) [450, 550)
```

Probability for each number:

```
~55% ~27% ~18%
```

With random value between 0 and 550, ex. `135` the selected number would be `1` since `0 <= 135 < 300`.

As to how you do this in C++, try it for yourself first.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help Peter. I really like your idea because the selection is made according to exact probabilities that are (as needed) proportionally and negatively related with the numbers´ values in the set. However, I face the problem that I need to loop over all numbers in the set, calculate a win probability and then loop over them again to select a winning number. This procedure unfortunately could compromise the efficiency of the whole program. Really a pity!

Answer (score 0):

What you're talking about is basically the [Geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution), or at least a chopped and normalized variant of it.

C++11 includes a [geometric distribution generator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/geometric_distribution), and you can use that directly if you like, but to keep things simple, you can also do something like this:

```
int genRandom(int count)
{
    while(true)
    {
        int x = 0;
        while(x < count-1)
        {
            if(rand() < RAND_MAX/2) // with probability 0.5...
            {
                return x;
            }
            x++;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that here I'm using rejection sampling to ensure that a value gets picked, rather than return count-1 if I run past it (which would give the last two items equal probability).

Comment: Thanks very much for your kind and detailed answer. Please correct me if I am wrong, but it seems that your proposal ignores the value of the number for win probability and may need to generate multiple random numbers until a number is finally selected. Is that right?

Comment: @José It doesn't directly use the value of the number, but it does indirectly use it. For instance, the function is less likely to return 5 than 2, because it would need to fail to return 2, 3, and 4 in order to return 5. It does generate multiple random numbers, yes.

Comment: Incidentally, the expected number of random numbers which are generated each time you call `genRandom(count)` is exactly 2, regardless of the value of `count`. That is, this function executes in average time `O(1)`.